# I want to transfer money from my bank account to somebody elses bitcoin account

Tags: money, deposit

I have no bitcoin account off my own. i want to deposit some money in a somebody else bitcoin account.

Comment: That's not possible. You'll need to buy BTC (from an exchange, or anyone who is willing to trade them) in order to send BTC.

Answer (score 1):

If your bank doesn't support Bitcoin payments, I think the nearest process you can get to a single direct transaction without a wallet is to find a BTM (Bitcoin ATM) that accepts payments using your bank debit card.

You would need a BTM that allows you to enter the recipients receiving address rather than a BTM that creates an intermediary wallet or account.